# Is there a Photoshop or Illustrator script that can see what functions & commands a user is executing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-scripting, illustrator-scripting

I'm writing scripts to automate some things and I would like to make it easier to identify what commands and functions a user is executing. Something like a plugin that monitors and then stores that information in a database or file would seem ideal.

Does this exist or is this possible in the Photoshop and Illustrator scripting environments?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. Scripting tells the **application** to do something, and does not control events outside the application environment (such as database input).

What you are seeking is something like a key logger or screen recorder.

Photoshop does offer a history log in its preferences.

It will spit out things like this, which still isn't what you are really asking for:

```
        2013-09-09 03:53:44 File Map.psd closed
        Close
2013-09-09 04:18:02 File Scan-130909-0003.tif opened
        Open
            01:Users:scott:Desktop:Scan-130909-0003.tif
    Levels
        Levels
            Preset Kind: Custom
            Adjustment: levels adjustment list
            levels adjustment
            Channel: composite channel
            Input: 75, 255
2013-09-09 04:18:21 File Untitled-1 opened
2013-09-09 04:18:21 File Default Type Styles.psp opened
        Make
            New: document
            Mode: RGB color mode
            Width: 8.5 Inches
            Height: 11 Inches
            Resolution: 150 per inch
            Pixel Aspect Ratio: 1
            Fill: transparent
            Depth: 8
            Profile:  “Display”
        Select previous document
        Select next document
    Drag Layer
    Reveal All
    Convert to Smart Object
        Convert to Smart Object
    Free Transform
        Transform
            Center: center
            Translate: 1.289 Inches, 1.527 Inches
            Width: 74.6%
            Height: 74.6%
            Angle: -8.7°
        Print Print Options of current document
            Printer Options
            With Color Management
            Intent: relative colorimetric
            false
            Printer Name:  “Xerox Phaser 3250”
            Proof Setup
            Builtin: working CMYK
            Proof Setup
            Builtin: working CMYK
            Print Output Options
            Without Caption
            Without Calibration Bars
            Without Registration Marks
            Without Corner Crop Marks
            Without Center Crop Marks
            Without Labels
            Without Negative
            Without Emulsion Down
            false
            Background Color: RGB color
            Red: 255
            Green: 255
            Blue: 255
            Border: 0 Inches
            Bleed: 0 Inches
            150 pixels
            With Include Vector Data
            Page Position: centered
            Left: -0.174 Inches
            Top: -0.174 Inches
            Print Scale: 100%
            false
            767
            0
            587
            0
             
            (data)...
             “”
        Print One Copy
```